# Как изменить QuerySet который я получаю при парсинге страницы?

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

При парсе страницы меня интересуют теги "p", но может быть так, что может не быть элемента с "жанрами фильма" или "временем фильма". Как в вытаскивающий QuerySet(список) добавить элемент, при этом проверять какого именно тега нет первого или второго?
Мой код:

```
def ParsePageP(host, url):
    b = ['<p>Неизвестно</p>']
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
    for item in bsObj.findAll("div", class_="session clear"):
        children = item.find_all('p')
        if(children[0].string == None):
            children[0].string = 'Неизвестно'
        # if(len(children) < 2):
        #     children.new_tag('b').append('Неизвестно')
        # print(children[1].text)
        print(children)


ParsePageP("https://cinemaciti.ua/", "https://cinemaciti.ua/fontan-sky-center/rozklad")
```

C закоментированым кодом (видно что нет второго тега "p" со временем данного фильма):

```
[<p>Неизвестно</p>, <p>153 хв.</p>]
[<p>жахи </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
[<p>комедія </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
[<p>драма, трилер </p>]
[<p>драма, пригоди, трилер, жахи </p>]
[<p>трилер </p>, <p>108 хв.</p>]
[<p>драма, трилер, екшн </p>]
[<p>комедія, жахи, фантастика </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
[<p>бойовик </p>, <p>120 хв.</p>]
[<p>жахи </p>, <p>135 хв.</p>]
[<p>детектив, трилер, жахи </p>, <p>95 хв.</p>]
[<p>бойовик, драма, трилер </p>, <p>114 хв.</p>]
[<p>мультфільм </p>, <p>87 хв.</p>]
[<p>фентезі </p>, <p>94 хв.</p>]
[<p>драма, кримінал, трилер </p>, <p>153 хв.</p>]
[<p>пригоди, фантастика </p>, <p>102 хв.</p>]
[<p>комедія </p>, <p>95 хв.</p>]
[<p>комедія, мультфільм </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
[<p>Неизвестно</p>, <p>136 хв.</p>]
[<p>пригоди, сімейний </p>, <p>118 хв.</p>]
```

Без закоментированого кода (ругаеться на код) либо (на list out of the range):

```
[<p>Неизвестно</p>, <p>153 хв.</p>]
[<p>жахи </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
[<p>комедія </p>, <p>99 хв.</p>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 47, in <module>
    ParsePageP("https://cinemaciti.ua/", "https://cinemaciti.ua/fontan-sky-center/rozklad")
  File "parse.py", line 17, in ParsePageP
    children.new_tag('b').append('Неизвестно')
  File "/home/chesterfield/dev/app_test_2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1578, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'new_tag'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь:

```
children.new_tag('b').append('Неизвестно')
```

Значение переменной  `children` не тег, но список, а применение метода `new_tag()` к списку не возможно.

Вы вероятно хотели добавить тег за последний элемент списка `children`:

```
children[-1].new_tag('b').append('Неизвестно')
```